# Glueing T-structures

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, derived-categories

Suppose I have triangulated categories $A \xrightarrow{i_{*}} B \xrightarrow{j^{*}} C$
where $i_{*},j^{*}$ have right adjoints $i^{*}, j_{*}$ respectively (they possibly also have left adjoints). Suppose further that for every $X \in B$ there is an exact triangle

$$i_{*}i^{*}X \to X \to j_{*}j^{*}X \to i_{*}i^{*}X[1]$$

I want to say that I can take two t-structures $A^{\leq 0}, C^{\leq 0}$ on $A$ and $C$ and glue them to t-structure on $B$. Can this actually be done?

My attempt was to take $B^{\leq 0}$ to be the full subcategory of objects $X: i^{*}X \in A^{\leq 0}, j^{*}X \in C^{\leq 0}$. However I can't seem to construct the required adjunction because of the non-functoriality of the cone. Is there an obvious way round this issue?

Answer (score 3):

All this is written in detail in Asterisque 100 (A.A. Beilinson, J. Bernstein, Pierre Deligne, Faisceaux pervers. Analysis and topology on singular spaces, I (Luminy, 1981), 5–171, Aste’risque 100, Soc. Math. France, Paris 1982).